# discord.js button on embed, errors with 'cannot send an empty message'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot send an embed with a button attached when it reads a certain message, but this error keeps coming up:

```
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message
```

I have tried looking for a few solutions online, but couldn`t find the right one for me.
This is my code, hope you can help me understand what is wrong.

```
const exampleEmbed = {
      color: 0xff0000,
      title: '◄◄ ‼ help request ‼ ►►',
      fields: [
        { name: `user:`, value: `${msg.author}` },
        { name: 'reason:', value: msg.content.slice(3) || 'no reason specified', inline: true }
      ],
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
    };



    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('Click me!')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            );


    const msgData = {
       content : `<@&${StaffRoleID}>`,
        embeds: [ exampleEmbed ],
        components: [ row ],
    }
    console.log(msgData);
      
     await msg.reply({data: msgData});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you placed `msgData` incorrectly. You don't need to insert it into object with `data` property. Just pass it directly to the `Message#reply` method.

```js
const msgData = {
    content : `<@&${StaffRoleID}>`,
    embeds: [ exampleEmbed ],
    components: [ row ],
}

await message.reply(msgData);
```

For some reason, documentation for `discord.js` does not provide clear information about which options should be passed into this method, but if you dig deeper, you can find [`BaseMessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.5.0/typedef/BaseMessageOptions) interface describing everything you can pass into the `Message#reply` method.